# How to turn Event into Command in Xamarin Forms MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, eventtocommand, xamarin-community-toolkit

**Tools:** I am using Xamarin forms & MVVM

I am following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mpe_1okwxk&list=PLwOF5UVsZWUiHY1CkRVjYJ6dm0iCvAlfw&index=12

**NuGet:** I have installed NuGet > xamarin.community.toolkit

**Error:**

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

***Debug:***

I am trying to Convert Collection ItemSelect Event Into a Command. I know issue is def with code that is trying to convert event to command But I am not sure how to go about debugging this error. Since app has entered in break state, I can't simple add break points. I did copy/paste outfile at bottom of this topic

Note if I remove code that convert event to command, that it works fine. So this means issue is with: `CollectionView.Behaviors` or `xct:ItemSelectedEventArgsConverter`

**View Page**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TestApp02_MVVM_Product.Views.ProductPage"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <xct:ItemSelectedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemSelectedEventArgsConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>    
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelectedEvent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            ...>
                <!-- Turn Event Into Command-->
                <CollectionView.Behaviors>
                    <xct:EventToCommandBehavior 
                        EventName="ItemSelected"
                        Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}"
                        EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ItemSelectedEventArgsConverter}"/>
                </CollectionView.Behaviors>
                ...
        </CollectionView>
...
```

***ViewModel***

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using TestApp02_MVVM_Product.Models;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp02_MVVM_Product.ViewModels
{
    class ProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableRangeCollection<ProductModel> ProductsList { get; set; }
        public AsyncCommand<ProductModel> ItemSelectedCommand { get; }
        
         public ProductViewModel()
        {
            ProductsList = new ObservableRangeCollection<ProductModel>();
            ProductsList.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Name 1", ProductDescription = "Description 1" });
            ProductsList.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Name 1", ProductDescription = "Description 1" });
            ProductsList.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Name 1", ProductDescription = "Description 1" });
            ProductsList.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Name 1", ProductDescription = "Description 1" });

            ItemSelectedCommand = new AsyncCommand<ProductModel>(OnItemSelectedCommand);
        }//end of con

        public ProductModel previousItemSelected;
        public ProductModel currentItemSelected;
        public ProductModel ItemSelectedEvent
        {
            get => currentItemSelected;
            set
            {
                currentItemSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        
        async Task OnItemSelectedCommand(ProductModel productModel)
        {
            if (productModel == null)
                return;

             await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Selected works", "yayyy", "Cancel");
        }
        ...


#region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

** Output **

```
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_is_assignable_from'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_is_assignable_from'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_is_assignable_from'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_float_array'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_float_array'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_float_array'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_set_float_array_region'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_set_float_array_region'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_set_float_array_region'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_float_array_region'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_float_array_region'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_float_array_region'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
[Mono] Requesting loading reference 11 (of 12) of /data/data/com.companyname.testapp02_mvvm_product/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll
[Mono] Loading reference 11 of /data/data/com.companyname.testapp02_mvvm_product/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment[0x793c9b6900] -> Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager[0x793c9f8300]: 3
[Mono] Requesting loading reference 12 (of 15) of /data/data/com.companyname.testapp02_mvvm_product/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll
[Mono] Loading reference 12 of /data/data/com.companyname.testapp02_mvvm_product/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Google.Android.Material[0x793c9f8b00] -> Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager[0x793c9f8300]: 4
[TabLayout] MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead
[Mono] Requesting loading reference 4 (of 11) of /data/data/com.companyname.testapp02_mvvm_product/files/.__override__/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.dll
[Mono] Loading reference 4 of /data/data/com.companyname.testapp02_mvvm_product/files/.__override__/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.CommunityToolkit[0x793c9f8500] -> System[0x794c9eb480]: 9
[Mono] Requesting loading reference 9 (of 11) of /data/data/com.companyname.testapp02_mvvm_product/files/.__override__/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.dll
[Mono] Loading reference 9 of /data/data/com.companyname.testapp02_mvvm_product/files/.__override__/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.CommunityToolkit[0x793c9f8500] -> System.Core[0x793c887980]: 5
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `SelectionChangedCommand`?

Comment: cool, I will look into how to add that in. thanks for that info!

Answer (score 0):

I was mixing up ListView with CollectionView. CollectionView already has buildin SelectionChangedCommand so no need for <CollectionView.Behaviors> stuff

Following code worked for me

***View***

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelectedEvent, Mode=TwoWay}"
             SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">
```

***ViewModel***

```
 public AsyncCommand<ProductModel> SelectionChangedCommand { get; }
 ...
 SelectionChangedCommand = new AsyncCommand<ProductModel>(OnSelectionChangedCommand);

 async Task OnSelectionChangedCommand(ProductModel productModel)
 {
        //item is not selected so do nothing
        if (productModel == null)
            return;

        //item is selcted so do logic here
           await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Selected works", "yayyy", "Cancel");
}
```